# Google OAuth keeps failing

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to implement sign-in based on Google OAuth2. Couldnt figure out the problem.

```
app.route('/auth/google').get(
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile email'] }));

    app.route('/auth/google/callback').get( 
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        req.session.user_id=req.user.id;
        res.redirect('/chat');
    });
```

```
 passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: 'GOOGLE-CLIENT-ID',
        clientSecret: 'GOOGLE-CLIENT-SECRET',
        callbackURL: "https://chat-roomproject.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback"
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        myDataBase.findOneAndUpdate({ googleId: profile.id }, 
          {
            $setOnInsert: {
              googleId: profile.id,
            },
          },function (err, user) {
          return cb(err, user.value);
        });
      }
    ));
```

It keeps redirecting to home page even after sign-in.

These are the logs.

```
2021-08-09T16:34:34.862956+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/google/callback?code=4%2F0AX4XfWh9LlA9ydQdyKwNx9sBUeFaSrMnC2RHJ4luL9fhjZ9OHlOoMljZlCmKz2jEHMTVTQ&scope=email+profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&authuser=0&prompt=none" host=chat-roomproject.herokuapp.com request_id=a5b37882-9e8e-4004-8340-07ed8cc532c5 fwd="157.48.190.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=441ms status=302 bytes=234 protocol=https


2021-08-09T16:34:35.157420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=chat-roomproject.herokuapp.com request_id=833924df-8397-4601-b718-d915d72856cc fwd="157.48.190.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=151 protocol=https
```

Comment: The login confirmation in user consent window does not necessarily mean that the login process finished successfuly. If you get returned to homepage, than your failureRedirect route was activated. Try to console.log the err before you return cb function in passport.use of Google Strategy.

Comment: .@Fide , console.log(err) prints 'null'

Comment: Hmm, that would show us, there is no error in the login procedure. Can you just log the user.value ?

Comment: Apparently I was missing this piece of code which adds new user to database: { upsert: true, new: true }....but i dont know how it works. Thank you @Fide .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{ upsert: true, new: true }
adds new user to database, and this was missing in the code.

This should work:

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: 'GOOGLE-CLIENT-ID',
        clientSecret: 'GOOGLE-CLIENT-SECRET',
        callbackURL: "https://chat-roomproject.herokuapp.com/auth/google/callback"
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        myDataBase.findOneAndUpdate({ googleId: profile.id }, 
          {
            $setOnInsert: {
              googleId: profile.id,
            },
          {upsert: true, new: true},

          },function (err, user) {
          return cb(err, user.value);
        });
      }
    ));
```